# Readwise: Yellow Highlight Not Displaying Color (Jinja2)

Tags: jinja2

I export my highlights from **Kindle** to **Readwise** then from **Readwise** to **Obsidian**.

In my kindle app, I use all the highlight colors for different purposes (Pink, Blue, Orange Yellow).  Readwise treats "Yellow" as the default so it doesn't create a color tag for this tag and I use Yellow for my more important highlights. What I'm trying to do is create a color tag

Here is my default code before changes:

```
- {{ highlight_text }}{% if highlight_location and highlight_location_url %} ([{{highlight_location}}]({{highlight_location_url}})){% elif highlight_location %} ({{highlight_location}}){% endif %}{% if highlight_tags %} {% for tag in highlight_tags %}#hl-{{tag}} {% endfor %}{% endif %}{% if highlight_note %}
    - Note: {{ highlight_note }}{% endif %}
```

So this is where I am stuck.. The code above works, but `#hl-yellow` will not display.. Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

**Update:**
So I was able to create a work around so all highlights begin with #`#hl` and the colors are added with if statements by adding `-red` `-blue` `-orange` instead of it being `#hl-red`, `#hl-blue`, and `#hl-orange`.

So now the output is `#hl` for yellow, `#hl-blue` for blue, `#hl-orange` for orange, and `#hl-red` for pink.

Is there any way I can subtract a certain amount of characters before I add a color? That way the default tag can be `#hl-yellow` and I can subtract 6 characters and then just replace the 6 characters from `yellow` with `red` `blue` `orange`. Is this possible?

Updated Code:

```
- {{ highlight_text }}{% if highlight_location and highlight_location_url %} ([{{highlight_location}}]({{highlight_location_url}})){% elif highlight_location %} ({{highlight_location}}){% endif %} #hl{% if highlight_tags %}{% for tag in highlight_tags %}{% if tag == "pink" %}-red{% elif tag == "orange" %}-orange{% elif tag == "blue" %}-blue{% else %}-yellow{% endif %} {% endfor %}{% endif %}{% if highlight_note %}
- Note: {{ highlight_note }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add ".yellow" to a note in Kindle then that note will be displayed in Readwise with a "yellow" tag.